# Immediate window display control’s property value

Tags: ms-access

I sometimes want to check a value of control property, for example TextBox width. Direct from the immediate window. Instead of using a sub. I try to write in the immediate those but it doesn’t work.

?TextBox.width
Debug.print TextBox.BackColor
?TextBox

Comment: my be, this TextBox not available in current context. Is TextBox real name of control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the full syntax:

```
? Forms!YourForm!TextBox.Width, Forms!YourForm!TextBox.BackColor
```